# How to choose same option twice

Tags: javascript

I open page, in dropdown is selected option (value="26"), but "rentDropDown" div is not showing. How to make it appear if the option is selected from the page opening

```
<select name="prop_action_category" id="prop_action_category_submit"   class="select-submit2" onchange="toggle(this)">
<option value="" disabled selected style="display:none;">Label</option>
<option value="-1">None</option>
<option class="level-0" value="26" selected="selected">1</option>
<option class="level-0" value="28">2</option>
</select>

<p class="half_form half_form_last" id="rentDropDown" style="display: block;">
 <select name="property_label" class="cd-select">
  <option value="">Default</option>
  <option value="/ 1">Per month</option>
  <option value="/ 2">Per week</option>
 </select>
</p>

function toggle(el){
          var value = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value,
          div = document.getElementById('rentDropDown');

          if (value === '28' || value ==='-1') {
              div.style.display = 'none';
          } else if (value === '26') {
              div.style.display = 'block';
         }
     }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "save form" mean in this context?

Comment: Consider posting a plunkr

Comment: I changed description little bit, hope it will be more clearly

Answer (score 1):

Just call your `toggle` function on page load:

```
toggle(document.getElementById('prop_action_category_submit'));
```

Comment: In the simplest case you can wrap it with <script></script> tag and put it before the closing </body> tag.